# DHCP reservation removal script

Tags: powershell, dhcp

At my office (about 7000 computers) every PC has an IPv4 reservation for security measures.

If a computer is replaced the reservation needs to be cleaned, but there are multiple scopes that it could be in.

I've created a script which searches for the MAC address you provide, through every scope but also generates an error at every scope where that MAC address is not found.

The removing of the IP reservation works but what I want the script to do is the following:
First it should search the list of scopes for the correct scope which the computer is in, then it should execute the code in which it actually removes the reservation.

Also, I tried giving a text output for when the MAC adress is not found in any scope at all, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Here's my code:

```
Write-Host "remove mac-address"
$Mac = Read-Host "Mac-Adres"
$ScopeList = Get-Content sometxtfilewithscopes.txt

foreach($Scope in $Scopelist) 
{
    Remove-DhcpServerv4reservation -ComputerName #ipofdhcpserver# -ClientId $Mac -ScopeId $scope -erroraction SilentlyContinue -PassThru -Confirm -OutVariable NotFound | Out-Null
}
if ($NotFound -eq $false ) {
    Write-Host "MAC-address not found!"
}

pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (this is what I use for something similar):

```
$mac = Read-Host "Enter MAC Address"
if ($mac -eq $null) { Write-Error "No MAC Address Supplied" -ErrorAction Stop }

$ServerName = "mydhcpserver.mydomain.net"
$ScopeList = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName $ServerName

ForEach ($dhcpScope in $ScopeList) {
    Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId $dhcpScope.ScopeId -ComputerName $ServerName | `
    Where {($_.ClientID -replace "-","").ToUpper() -eq $mac.ToUpper()} | `
    ForEach {
        Try {
            Remove-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ClientId $_.ClientID -ScopeId $dhcpScope.ScopeId -Server $ServerName -WhatIf
        } catch {
            Write-Warning ("Error Removing From Scope" + $dhcpScope.ScopeId)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Fazer87,
i've tried to use bits and pieces of your code, unfortunately it doesnt work, i tried not giving any input for $mac but it does not return "No MAC Address Supplied"

also the error handling part between try and catch does not generate any errors even if i purposely enter an invalid mac address.

might be my fault but i got my code working!

thanks a lot for your help, i put some of your code to good use and it works like a charm!

Comment: it would be nice to have some sort of error response though when the mac address isnt found.

Answer (score 1):

Just let PowerShell do all the heavy lifting for you:

```
$mac = Read-Host 'Enter MAC address'

$server = 'yourdhcpserver'

$reservation = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -Computer $server |
               Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation -Computer $server |
               Where-Object { $_.ClientId -eq $mac }

if ($reservation) {
  $reservation | Remove-DhcpServerv4Reservation -Computer $server
} else {
  "$mac not found."
}
```

The above assumes that the entered MAC address has the form `##-##-##-##-##-##`. If you want to allow colons as well (`##:##:##:##:##:##`) you need to replace the colons with hyphens before using the address in the `Where-Object` filter:

```
$mac = $mac -replace ':', '-'
```

Comment: For some reason powershell says that im running the dhcp search on my local pc when i enter this script while it clearly defines that it should search the $server for dhcp scopes... thoughts?

Comment: @MauritsKipperman My mistake. You need to tell each DHCP cmdlet the target computer.